# show the convergence of the sequence using the definition of limit

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

using the definition of limit I should prove the convergence of this sequence:

$u_n = \frac{\sqrt(n - 1)!}{(1 + \sqrt1)(1 + \sqrt2)(1 + \sqrt3) ... (1 + \sqrt n)}$

a hint provided is that the limit is 0.

so far I've reached here in the proof:

we want 
$| u_n - 0| = | u_n| =  \frac{\sqrt(n - 1)!}{(1 + \sqrt1)(1 + \sqrt2)(1 + \sqrt3) ... (1 + \sqrt n)} < \varepsilon$

I am stuck on what to choose $n_0$ to be in order to have $n_0 \ge n$ and the rest of the proof.
any help is very appreciated.

Comment: $n \ge n_0$ sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT:**

$$\frac{\sqrt{(n-1)!}}{(1+\sqrt 1)(1+\sqrt 2)\cdots(1+\sqrt n)}\le \frac{\sqrt{(n-1)!}}{\sqrt{n!}}$$

Comment: !  Please, "My please" my-ght be some bad grammar

Comment: @HexaFlexagon You're welcome.  My pleasure.  -Mark

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**. One may observe that, for $n \ge1$,
$$
|u_n|=\frac1{\left|\left(1+\dfrac1{\sqrt{1}} \right)\left(1+\dfrac1{\sqrt{2}} \right)\cdots \left(1+\dfrac1{\sqrt{n}} \right)\right|}\cdot \frac1{\sqrt{n}}\le \frac1{\sqrt{n}}.
$$

Comment: @HexaFlexagon You are welcome.